# Как правильно оформить вставную конструкцию в предложении?

Tags: вставная-конструкция

А вот и предложение:

***Его вторая жена, красавица, умница(,) – вы её только что видели(,) – вышла за него, когда уже он был стар,  отдала ему молодость, красоту... ***

Это предложение **весьма интересное.**

**Во-первых,** оно встречается у А.П.Чехова в двух произведениях:

«Леший» — комедия в 4 действиях, написана в 1889 году. «Дядя Ваня» — пьеса с подзаголовком «Сцены из деревенской жизни в четырёх действиях». Окончательно завершена в 1896 году.

**Во-вторых,** оно имеет три варианта пунктуации (поэтому запятые стоят в скобочках):

**Две  запятые**: *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница,— вы ее видели,— вышла за него...* («Леший»). https://ilibrary.ru/text/968/p.1/index.html

**Нет запятых:**  *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него…* («Дядя Ваня», также у Розенталя).https://ilibrary.ru/text/972/p.1/index.html

**Вторая запятая:**  *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница — вы ее только что видели, — вышла за него…* («Дядя Ваня», также встречается  в современных учебных текстах). http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=2675&public_page=2

Какой из них правильный и как объяснить каждый вариант?

**Комментарий**

1) Надо сказать, что эта тема в Правилах Розенталя, где  объясняются все возможные варианты (нет запятых, первая запятая, вторая запятая, две запятые, симметрия запятых) **кажется мне излишне формальной.** Она «напрягает» корректоров и редакторов и мало что дает читателю. Какой смысл в разных вариантах постановки запятых, различаются ли они по семантике (при восприятии письменного текста, а также на слух, по интонации)?

Для сравнения, **в справочнике Валгиной** (1994 год) такой детализации нет. Запятые у нее ставятся по условиям контекста,  также допускается постановка единого знака «запятая – тире» (вероятно, у Розенталя это симметрия знаков).

2) Мне, к примеру,  кажется, что в  варианте с одной  второй запятой **вставка как бы примыкает к обособленному приложению,** в то время как по смыслу она  относится ко всему предложению.

3) А как вам такой вариант:  ***Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него…***

Это если убрать обособленное приложение:   Его вторая жена — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него…

Также **неплох вариант с двумя запятыми**:  он дает такое же понимание вставной конструкции, но не убирает запятые.

4) **А это другое объяснение, взяток из Интернета**:  *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница – вы её только что видели, – вышла за него, когда уже он был стар* (запятая после вставной конструкции выделяет обособленное приложение: Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, вышла за него).

Практически оно соответствует **формальному варианту с перенесенной запятой,**  только вот та ли это запятая, которую надо переносить?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Я приведу пример из современной литературы, в котором **вставка относится к обособленной конструкции** (придаточному предложению), вот тогда действительно уместна вторая запятая (и симметричный вариант тоже не подойдет). Это та постановка запятых, которая определяется не механически (по формальным правилам), а именно по контексту, как у Валгиной.

*А ведь эта девочка, **лицо которой память так и не смогла проявить до конца – оно расплывалось и ускользало, как пейзаж Моне, –** была до отказа набита ценными сведениями.*

Comment: Меня это предложение тоже напрягло, когда читал правила Розенталя. Так понимаю, что "красавица, умница" — это обособленное приложение и закрыть его в любом случае нужно. Так? Просто у Розенталя вообще не обособляется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите свое мнение в виде ответа.  1) У них перенесена запятая, которая закрывает обособленное приложение. 2) Почему Розенталь не ставит запятых вообще? Это случайность или есть объяснение?

Comment: Для ответа мне нужно у вас уточнить. У Розенталя получается так: *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница вышла за него.* Можно ли теоретически без запятой после "умница"? Думаю, что нет.

Comment: Думаю, что нет, а иначе какая здесь грамматика?

Comment: Вопрос о предложении (весьма интересном), которое дано вроде бы как цитата: разве у А.П. — запятые тоже в скобочках? Думаю, что ссылка на автора там не к месту.

Comment: Мне тоже ближе ваш вариант. К тому же а пособии "Курс современного русского языка" постановка запятой объясняется так. Его вторая жена, красавица, умница – вы её только что видели, – вышла за него, когда уже он был стар (постановка тире вместо скобок факультативна; запятая после вставной конструкции выделяет обособленное приложение: Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, вышла за него).

Comment: Серж, да, они считают, что здесь перенесенная запятая, но я думаю, что это тот случай, когда запятую переносить нельзя.

Comment: В справочниках говорится, что запятая переносится после скобок. Если же следовать правилам, то, действительно, запятая должна закрывать обособленное приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с звумя запятыми ничем кроме "симметрии" (Розенталь её миролюбиво допускает, исходя из издательской практики и приводя пример) не оправдать. Поскольку такое не обязательно, я бы уклонился от этой возможности. Вариант без запятой не проходит, поскольку при изъятии вставленной конструкции с отступлением она должна бы появиться, замыкая уточнение (его жена, столбовая дворянка, делала то-то). Располагаться она должна в начале, а не после вставки (которая находится между парой тире) к которой не относится (иначе выходит  вставка предложения между словом и следующей после него запятой). Поэтому я бы выбрал ваш **вариант под номером 3)**.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. 1) Мне кажется, что  симметричный вариант мог бы чаще применяться в тех случаях, когда  запятых много, а вставка имеет нейтральный смысл. 2) Я думаю, что  вариант со второй запятой  ближе к формальным правилам (чеховский текст, вероятно, правится сейчас по этому принципу), вот из-за этого они мне не нравятся.  И обратите внимание, что у Чехова или нет запятых, или парный знак, то есть он предпочитает симметрию.

Answer (score 1):

1) *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, — вы ее видели, — вышла за него...*
Здесь симметрия. Симметрия сопоставима с графическим тире. Это не профессионально, зато понятно (не возникает вопросов). Здесь это не очень желательно, так как аж четыре знака разделяют простое предложение.

2) *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него...*
Запятая должна закрывать обособленное приложение. Без этого аж три "разных" лица. Не знаю, как Розенталь это пропустил. Тоже симметрия.

3) *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница — вы ее только что видели, — вышла за него…*
Здесь вставная конструкция относится к обособленному приложению: *вы только что видели красавицу и умницу*. То есть подчёркиваются эти качества.

4) *Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него…*
Вставная конструкция относится (структурно) к подлежащему "жена", так как приложение закрыто запятой. Этот вариант больше всего нравится, так как именно это слово (а не обособленные качества) является ключевым в смысле предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, комментарии такие. 1) Я не считаю симметричный (понятный) знак "непрофессиональным", мне вот кажется непрофессиональной излишняя детализация, которая может привести к не лучшему решению. 2)  Вероятно, это авторский вариант. 3)  Там два обособленных  приложения, вставка относится ко второму? 4)  Да, это хороший вариант, но не он используется в чеховском тексте.

Comment: 1) Не вижу никакого смысла в симметрии, кроме самой симметрии. Она противоречит правилам Розенталя, в которых сохраняются обычные пунктуационные принципы. Розенталь просто делает примечание, что такое существует в литературе. Похоже на @@ приметки Грамоты, что в литературе встречаются случаи необособления вводных слов. Но это не даёт нам право их не обособлять. Про "излишнюю детализацию" — без таких спорных случаев было бы скучно. 3) К обоим (в ответе же есть пример). Уточнение цельное по структуре, так как уточняется одно слово, в отличие от "цветов Японии", где можно понять двояко.

Comment: Одна лирика!  И полное отсутствие какой-либо внятной позиции  по данной теме.  Или, вернее сказать, она размазана у Вас, как каша по тарелке. Вы хотя бы приглядитесь к фразе "умница — вы ее только что видели". Вставка относится к слову "умница" (а не к обоим приложениям, как у вас), а должна относиться ко всему предложению. И т.д.

Comment: Пунктуационные принципы — закрывать обороты, как обычно. Моя позиция, что к обоим словам: между ними можно поставить "и", чего не сделать после подлежащего. А как нам отнести ко всему приложению однозначно? Никак. У нас тут нет блоков, как в языках программирования. Нет, тут нельзя разделять отношение к двум словам. Иначе меняем местами и получается так: *умница — вы ее только что видели, — красавица*. По смыслу оно относится ко всем трём словам. Но грамматически — или ко всему приложению, или к подлежащему. А так к одному: *красивая, умная — диссертацию пишет*. Тут можно поменять местами.

Comment: Не стоит во всем винить неадыкватность. Мнения здесь, как вы сами сказали, разные. Я всегда не просто говорю, а аргументирую. У вас аргументация не всегда, и часто она размазана (нечёткая). Увы, здесь нужно, как в математике, доказывать так, чтобы ни у кого не возникло сомнений. А если сомнения есть, то на них нужно указывать также чётко (а не "вообще вас не понимаю" — это ни о чём).

Comment: Доказательствами вы часто называете суждения, в которых что-то доказываете самому себе, при этом часто бывает непонятно, ЧТО именно вы доказываете. В этом предложении вставка по смыслу однозначно относится к подлежащему "жена", именно ее  "видели" (и это нужно обозначить расстановкой запятых). Чтобы это понять, надо убрать приложение, которое является субъективным мнением говорящего:  Его жена — вы ее только что видели — вышла за него... Видеть, что она красавица и уж тем более умница с первого взгляда затруднительно. С этим вариантом согласились еще двое участников, поэтому вопрос ЗАКРЫТ.

Comment: Согласен (про вариант). Вы тоже часто непонятно объясняете даже для меня: куча суперсложных терминов — это очень круто, но это всё нужно гуглить и изучать, чтобы вас понять. У задающих вопрос вряд ли получится изучить всю терминологию самостоятельно. И захотят ли они это делать...

Comment: Мне часто говорили, что я понятно объясняю. Но я всё-таки учту Ваше замечание, спасибо.

Comment: Говорили люди с соответствующими знаниями. Чаще всего ответы понятны. Просто иногда сложные термины не дают понять мысль. Те, кто не понял, не будут уточнять, так как научные термины, увы, обычно не вызывают у людей интереса и, наоборот, отпугивают. Но это всё равно звучит круто. Нужен баланс.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ответ Граммы.ру.

В данном случае более правильным является такое оформление (поясняется слово жена):
Его вторая жена, красавица, умница, - вы ее только что видели - вышла за него замуж, когда он уже был стар, отдала ему молодость.

Отсутствие в справочнике Розенталя запятой перед или после вставной конструкции трудно объяснить. Возможно, это ошибка.
Теоретически возможно такое оформление: Его вторая жена, красавица, умница - вы ее только что видели, - вышла за него замуж, когда он уже был стар, отдала ему молодость. В этом случае вставная конструкция поясняет приложение красавица (вставная конструкция может пояснять любое слово предложения, в том числе приложение).

С уважением
GRAMMA.RU

Comment: Серж, большое спасибо  за ценную информацию, всё-таки коллективный разум - это вещь!  Мое мнение после Вашего сообщения немного изменилось. С одной стороны, есть объективные факторы, позволяющие нам отнести вставку к какой-то части предложения, С другой стороны, есть еще и авторский элемент, который надо учитывать. В конце концов, можно представить себе эмоциональную речь персонажа, который объединяет в один блок приложение и вставку:  "красавица, умница - вы ее только что видели (и поэтому могли в этом убедиться).

Comment: Вы правы. Всегда доверяю этому порталу. Отвечающий на вопросы синтаксиса - д.ф.н.

Comment: А на Справке Грамоты ответы профессиональнее? Есть ли разница, где спрашивать?

Comment: @oleedd,вы имеете в виду Грамоту.ру?

Comment: Ну да..........

Comment: На Грамме более профессиональные ответы. Грамота на сложные вопросы не отвечает, и дрбиться от них ответа - тяжело. А Грамма отвечает на самые сложеые вопросы.