# Нужна ли запятая перед первым тире при обособлении вставки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

*За аттестатом Вера плыла на сцену медленно, растягивала момент, как гармошку. Юлька, которую вызвали раньше, взлетела туда в три шага, потеряв по дороге одну из своих страшенных туфель – засмеялась. Опять эти ямочки! **Три мальчика, вот болваны (,) – и красавцы, на подбор, – побежали к сцене,** пока эта золушка прыгала там на одной ноге, и чуть не передрались из-за её туфли.*

Как объяснить  выбор решения?

Спасибо!

Comment: Тут вставка внутри вставки. Заметили?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю грамматику этого предложения. Вы, наверное, имели в виду вставку внутри обособленного оборота?. А потом это же приложения, а не вставные конструкции, там вроде бы свои особенности. И еще просьба: отвечайте в поле ответа, даже если это короткая реплика. Так удобнее: можно принять ответ, да и модераторы не  разрешают  комментарии, похожие на ответы.

Comment: Для ответа символов маловато. Система столько не пропустит. Да и на ответ оно никак не похоже, просто заметил это. Обособленный оборот, который, по сути, является вставкой. Там не приложение, там характеристика автора в связи с происходящим. Не будь там внутренней вставки, "вот болваны" оформлялось бы двумя тире.

Comment: Вот и расскажите всё это в ответе. У нас для приложений свои правила, на них надо ссылаться. Помните, у Розенталя был пример с двумя обособленными приложениями (про собаку Фунтика).

Comment: Для ответа у меня другое есть, по сути дела, но у нас же не совпадают взгляды в этом вопросе. Не помню, не читал пример про собаку. Если расширить, то вставочность становится очевидной: *вот же ж они болваны*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятую там не нужно ставить, потому что там ряд существительных (*болваны и красавцы*), второе существительное примыкает к первому, относится к нему грамматически, по согласованию (падеж). Тире (вставка) употребляется в связи с контрастом.

Случай очень нестандартный (из разряда проверки на прочность, правила на такое каверзное не рассчитаны). По логике надо сначала закрыть внутреннюю вставку (тире), а потом внешнюю (запятой), но правила такое не позволяют (запятую после тире), поэтому приходится делать наоборот.

Можно ещё предложить вариант с интонационным тире внутри вставки (просто для ознакомления, понятно, что тире внутри вставки желательно не использовать):
*Три мальчика – вот болваны – и красавцы, на подбор – побежали к сцене...*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё как-то смутно...  Дала свой вариант.  Не знаю, насколько он верен. А где же наши специалисты-грамматики, никто не помогает.  Хотелось бы узнать, почему?

Comment: Не согласен, что там приложение. Сравнить: *Три мальчика, три болвана, побежали к сцене...* Слово "вот" в приложениях не используется, оно указывает на чей-то взгляд, взгляд со стороны — то есть на комментарий, вставку.

Comment: Девушка и смотрит со стороны, завидует подружке (вот ведь какие болваны). Оценочное приложение

Comment: И "*вот ведь какие болваны*" — это приложение? Соглашусь, если приложение внутри вставки.

Comment: А чем это вам не приложение? ВОТ - это вообще частица, она вполне может относиться к любому слову. Я просто содержание книги лучше знаю. Она сначала называет их болванами, а потом уж отмечает, что они еще и самые красивые, что еще неприятнее для нее.

Comment: Просто привык, что приложение иначе называет предмет — и это реальный факт, а не чьё-то мнение. А субъективная оценка чего-то — это уже вставная конструкция, тем более обзывание.

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd. Принимаю ваш ответе, и прежде всего, за его соответствие книжному авторскому варианту. Мы немного по-разному понимаем грамматику, но вы помогли мне объяснить тот вариант, который ближе мне.  Синонимии же в синтаксисе всегда достаточно, да и семантика может пониматься по-разному – в этом еще раз пришлось убедиться на этом примере! Спасибо вам!

Comment: Нашёл в примере Булгакова 2 ошибки (об этом в комментарии под другим ответом). Можно обсудить. Розенталь бы такое не пропустил. Хотя одну хитрую ошибку у Толстого пропустил.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, можно рассмотреть такие варианты:

*Три мальчика – **вот болваны! и красавцы на подбор!** – побежали к сцене...*

*Три мальчика (**вот болваны! И красавцы на подбор!**) побежали к сцене...*

И такой:

*Три мальчика – **вот болваны! (И красавцы на подбор!)** – побежали к сцене...*

**Примечание:** запятой перед «на подбор» не требуется.

Comment: Радует, что вы тоже первую характеристику относите к вставке. А почему И с прописной во втором варианте?

Comment: _oleedd: А почему И с прописной во втором варианте?_ === К сожалению, употребление строчной после восклицательного знака не приветствуется современными правилами.

Comment: Но в первом примере же строчная...

Comment: Пришлось на это пойти из-за выделения вставки с помощью тире.

Comment: Скобки от этого не спасают. В любом случае нельзя писать И с прописной, потому что тогда после первого восклицательного знака предложение заканчивается, а это недопустимо (ведь после вставки идёт продолжение). В скобках может быть либо фраза (со строчной), либо предложение (с прописной), но не и то и то (как у вас).

Comment: **oleedd**, см. §97: _Безусловно необходимы скобки при сложной структуре вставки: Подкараулил этого кота гражданин в тот момент, когда животное с вороватым видом (**что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид? Это не оттого, что они порочны, а оттого, что они боятся, чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они — собаки и люди — не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то и другое очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да, нет никакой!**), да, так с вороватым видом кот собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи (Булг.)._  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128

Comment: Булгаков там перемудрил, мини-рассказ вставил в скобки, а одним предложением то всё не оформить. Так точно не стоит делать, это исключение, оно обусловлено размером текста (пришлось выкручиваться). Розенталь разрешает строчную после восклицательного знака: ***Примечание. Восклицательный знак может ставиться в восклицательных предложениях после каждого однородного члена для обозначения эмоциональной, прерывистой речи: Играл! проигрывал! в опеку взят указом!* (Гр.)** Так что можете исправить.

Comment: slava, а вам я очень обрадовалась – почти как человек на необитаемом острове. Мне казалось, что  в зале больше никого не осталось – все ушли и плотно закрыли за собой дверь. И варианты у вас оригинальные, эмоциональные.   Наши разговорные реплики  вообще интересны, и поэтому допускают разную запись. В примере из Булгакова я бы не стала писать строчную букву сразу после скобок  (по моему восприятию,  тогда хотя многоточие надо поставить). Но возможно это сохраненная авторская орфография.

Comment: В примере Булгакова гораздо логичнее начать в скобках с прописной, так как там не фраза вставляется, а текст (несколько предложений). У Булгакова там аж 2 ошибки. 1) *Чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они, не **причинил**.* Вставка должна изыматься без нарушения структуры, она не может влиять на согласование. 2) После "*чем они*" должна стоять запятая, потому что "*собаки и люди*" относится не к кошкам ("*они*"), а к существам более сильным, что до сравнительного оборота. Уже не затрагиваю сочетание "*причинить обиду*", которое можно посчитать художественным.

Comment: Обсудить можно, но чуть позже (тема довольно смутная.). И наверное, лучше в личной беседе., если вас интересует мое мнение.  ОК?

Comment: Ну ок..........

Answer (score 0):

1. Здесь, наверное, так.

Девушка дает подруге две оценки: (1) вот болваны; (2) и красавцы, на подбор. При этом по времени они как бы разделены, так что получается, что  **вторая оценка идет как вставка.**

*Три мальчика, вот болваны, побежали к сцене...*  Это обособленное приложение.

Но к этому обособленному приложению относится вставка, обособленная двумя тире, при этом первая запятая опускается (тесная связь):

***Три мальчика, вот болваны – и красавцы, на подбор, – побежали к сцене...***

Вторая запятая структурная, она закрывает обособленное приложение.  Такое оформление в книге.

2. Вот и получается вставка, отнесенная  обособленному приложению. Где эту тему можно найти у Розенталя?
3. **Сравнить** с предложением (из литературы, здесь разбирали):

Его вторая жена, КРАСАВИЦА, УМНИЦА, – вы её только что видели – вышла за него, когда он был уже стар.  Но здесь другое оформление, как вам это нравится?

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457032/Как-правильно-оформить-вставную-конструкцию-в-предложении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Кстати, можно вспомнить, какими активными мы были...